# WIX BURN Variable not updating from custom BA UI

Tags: wix, burn

I have a custom UI bootstrap application I have created several variables in my wxs For example

```
 <Variable Name="INSTALLSQL"
              Value="false" />
```

and I have included an install condition for the EXE and MSI packages

```
 <ExePackage PerMachine='yes'
                  Id="sql"
                  InstallCondition="INSTALLSQL"
                  SourceFile="..\..\Lib\SQLExpressInstaller\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe"
                  Permanent="yes" />
      <MsiPackage Id="epicor"
                   InstallCondition="InstallEpicor"
                  SourceFile="..\installerpackages\EpicorServiceInstaller.msi"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
```

In my C# code I have setup properties that the UI can update. I was hoping this would update the variable in burn but it doesn't seem to?

```
   public bool InstallSQL
        {
            get { return bool.Parse(Engine.StringVariables["INSTALLSQL"]); }
            set
            {

                Engine.StringVariables["INSTALLSQL"] = value.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to provide the user options as to what packages they want to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced "true" and "false" strings with 0 and 1 now things seem to work like expected.